Add custom keys to type with a generic
I have the following types and function:
interface Values {
  width: number;
  height: number;
};

interface Opts<T extends string> {
  requiredKeys: (keyof Values | NoInfer<T>)[];
  customParsers: Record<T, (text: string) => unknown>;
}

function example<T extends string>(opts: Partial<Opts<T>>): Partial<Values>;

I am trying to make it so they keys from Opts['customParsers'] also appear on the return type of example, extending Values; for example:
example({
  customParsers: {
    x: text => parseInt(text),
  },
}; // returns { width?: number, height?: number, x?: number }

I am not sure how I'd go about this. I've tried the following which unfortunately didn't work:
type Values<T extends Opts<string>> = {
  width: number;
  height: number;
} & {
  [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[K]>;
};


Since you already specified that customParsers will have a return type which is unknown, ReturnType should always resolve to unknown, if you hover customParsers.x you'll see that it has a return type which is unknown, even thought you're returning a number.

What is the proper way of typing this then? I thought using any wasn't a great idea for this. Would any work better? @HairyHandKerchief23

using any would result in the same problem, the problem is that each function of your customParsers record will have a different return type, it will not be inferred on its own

Is there any way to infer the return type from the keys passed but still type the parameters normally?

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz That's looking pretty good, unfortunately trying to pass a key from customParsers into requiredKeys errors, as shown here

This looks like a place where NoInfer doesn't actually work as advertised. You could just remove NoInfer as shown here and then you get the overall behavior you want (good things have no error, bad things have an error) although possibly the error you get for bad things isn't where you want it to be. Not sure how to proceed here. The wrinkle with NoInfer seems to be larger in scope than the question you're trying to ask (since it looks like a TS bug or design limitation)

@jcalz I think that's close enough for my use case. Could you please create an answer so I can accept it properly?

I'll do so when I get a chance.

In order to keep track of this you need Opts to maintain a relationship between each key of customParsers and the corresponding return type of the method. That means you will probably want Opts to be generic in an object type T, like this:
interface Opts<T extends object> {
    requiredKeys: (keyof (Values & T))[];
    customParsers: { [K in keyof T]: (text: string) => T[K] }
}

declare function example<T extends object>(
    opts: Partial<Opts<T>>
): Partial<Values & T>;

Here we can see that customParsers is a mapped type over T, so that each property of customParsers at key K is a method that accepts a string input and produces a T[K] output.
And requiredKeys is an array of element type keyof (Values & T), where the intersection Values & T is effectively the output type of example(), and so requiredKeys should be some set of keys of that type.
Note  that I removed the use of the NoInfer utility type because it isn't strictly necessary (you will get errors if requiredKeys contains elements not present as keys of customParsers or "width" or "height") and because keeping it there actually prevents inference you need.  Maybe it should stay there and someone should file an issue about NoInfer in the TypeScript repo, but that's probably out of scope for this question.
Let's test it:
const ret = example({
    requiredKeys: ['x'],
    customParsers: {
        x: text => parseInt(text),
    },
});
ret.height?.toFixed(1);
ret.width?.toFixed(1);
ret.x?.toFixed(1);

Looks good. The type of T is inferred as {x: number}, and so the output type Partial<Values & {x: number}> behaves as desired.
Playground link to code
